# Selection Sort doesn't output as expected

Tags: c

I have this assignment for my C class. She gave us pseudo code for the selection sort. There's some other requisites, but those I don't need help with. I followed her code, and even looked online for sample code. And mine follows the same concept but it never works. When I print the "sorted" array, it prints the unsorted numbers and a bunch of other numbers. If I enter '8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1' my array prints '8765432146142368001234567846142368'.

```
#define MAXSIZE 10

void print_array(const int a[], int size);

int main()
{
   int get_numbers(int n[]); //Function to retrieve a list of numbers and 
   returns an array of the numbers

   int numbers[MAXSIZE]; //Array to store unsorted list of numbers

   void selection_sort(int a[], int size);

   puts("Enter each number then press enter. (Ctrl + Z) to end.");
   get_numbers(numbers);
   selection_sort(numbers, MAXSIZE);  
   print_array(numbers, MAXSIZE);
}

void get_numbers(int n[])
{
   int s; //Stores return value of scanf
   int i; //Stores amount of values entered

   for(i = 0; (s = scanf("%i", &n[i])) != EOF; i++);

   if(i == 0)
   {
      puts("Error: No numbers entered.");
   }else if(i > MAXSIZE)
   {
      puts("Error: Too many values entered.");
      print_array(n, MAXSIZE);
   }else
   {
      print_array(n, MAXSIZE);
   }
}

void print_array(const int a[], int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%i", a[i]);
    }
}

void selection_sort(int a[], int size)
{
   void swap(int n[], int i, int min_index);
   for(int i = 0; i < (size - 1); i++)
   {
      int min = a[i];
      int min_index = i;
      for(int j = (i + 1); j < size; j++)
      {
         if(a[j] < min)
         {
            min = a[j];
            min_index = j;
         }
      }
      swap(a, i, min_index);
   }
}

void swap(int n[], int i, int min_index)
{
    int temp = n[i];
    n[i] = n[min_index];
    n[min_index] = temp;
}
```

Comment: You really need to debug your code but, OK, let's start with: "get_numbers" never returns a value. What is it supposed to return - perhaps the number of values entered? Then - you're passing `MAXSIZE` to `selection_sort`. Are you *always* entering `MAXSIZE` values? What will the program do if you enter fewer or more values than `MAXSIZE`?

Comment: Bob I see what you're saying, this is after much of my own failed debugging. At one point it did sort based on how many values are in the array. I also see what you mean for get_numbers. I'll change that to void.

Comment: Your program needs to remember **how many** values were entered. (this is your`i` variable after the loop) You should also check the array bounds before assigning.

Comment: Why are you writing function prototypes in main? Also, adding a space between the printed values could make your outputs clearer.

Comment: Perhaps `get_numbers` should return the number of values read in, and that the number of values read should be passed on to the other functions.

Comment: Bob I added the spaces like you said, the output gives me this '8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 44176288 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 44176288 0' it looks like it does sort it, but whats with these other numbers? Also, the local prototypes are what i've been told to do if they're only used by one function.

Comment: You are sorting MAXSIZE elements in the array, but with your input you only filled 8 elements in the array. Reading the last two uninitialized values is undefined behavior, you must not do that. In your case it happens that the array is randomly filled, one value is 0, the other 44176288.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few issues with your program.

Function prototypes need to be declared before any other functions.

If they bail out early/late, you need to pass the value of i to print_array. If you pass MAXSIZE you will be reading/writing to memory that isn't yours. Which is why you get weird values.

Comment: Thank you, I mention some of this in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone and their tips! I took what Bob Jarvis had mentioned (sorting based on exact number of values, spacing my output). My main problem was that it seemed to be printing a bunch of random numbers which I was unsure where it came from. After spacing I realized it does sort them but there was a random number ex. 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 44176288 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 44176288 0. After some more debugging I realized that I was also printing not at exact array size. After fixing all the different sizes it was fixed.